# threads to perform statistical calculations on list of numbers input on commad line?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to write a multi threaded program that takes a list of numbers from the command line and calculates various statistical values eg average, sum etc using separate worker threads. i have created three threads in this program and it compiles but i get errors. I am new to C and thread programming, please guide me in passing data to the thread for calculations?
This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define NUM_THREAD 3

int average, min, max;

void *
doSomeThing(void *param)
{

    //int *id_ptr, taskid;
    int *argv = (int *) param;
    sleep(1);
    //id_ptr=(int *) threadid;
    //taskid= *id_ptr;
    int j;
    int sum = 0;
    int upper = atoi(param);

    sleep(1);
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    unsigned long i = 0;


    if (id = 1) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < upper; i++) {
            sum += argv[i];
        }
        printf("sum of no's is :\n", sum);
    }
    if (id = 2) {
        printf("\n Second thread processing\n");
    }
    if (id = 3) {
        printf("\n Third thread processing\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < -1; i++);
    {
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREAD];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int *taskid[NUM_THREAD];
    int i = 0;
    int t;
    int err;
    //int input,a;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /*
    printf("how many no's do u want to evaluate?:\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("Enter the no's:\n");
    for (a = 0; a < input; a++) {
        arr[a] = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));
        scanf("%d", &arr[a]);
        printf("data:", &arr[a]);
    }
    */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREAD; t++) {
        taskid[t] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *taskid[t] = t;
        printf("In main: creating thread %d\n", t);
        err = pthread_create(&threads[t], &attr, doSomeThing, argv[1]);

        if (err) {
            printf("Error; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n",
                   err);
            exit(-1);

        }
    }
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREAD; t++) {
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
        printf("Joining thread %d\n", t);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: horrific formatting there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page. It is difficult to read badly indented code; please ensure your code is presented properly indented.  Don't use tabs; replace them with (four — recommended) spaces.  And please do explain in detail the errors you are getting, and provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can reproduce more easily the problems you see.  The input data and other code (e.g. the `main()` that launches the threads) will probably be relevant too.  ……Oh……`main()` is in there, indented about 5 levels deep! Ow!

Comment: What makes you think pthread_create assigns a nice little number like 1, 2, 3 as a thread_id?  When you call `pthread_self()`, it is unlikely that you will get 1, 2, or 3.  Also you should eventually `free` the memory you obtained from `malloc`.

Comment: I wish professors would wait until the students are competent programmers before trying to teach them threads. Or at least have a decent hardware perspective. But I guess that takes years and they don't have that sort of time.

Comment: I wash in a rush, i'll try to properly indent the code. But thankyou for the help and yes i am really struggling with threads. i will initialize the task id but how do i pass the user input to the thread for calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think `pthread_create` assigns a nice little number like 1, 2, 3 as a thread_id? When you call `pthread_self()`, it is unlikely that you will get 1, 2, or 3. Also you should eventually `free` the memory you obtained from `malloc`.

My suggestion is that you write a separate function for average, max, and min and call pthread_create explicitly 3 times passing in the 3 separate functions instead of using one function to do all.